# Using a batch file, merge pdf files in an order in a specific folder using pdftk

Tags: pdf, batch

I am currently using pdftk and able to merge the multiple pdf files in a folder to a single pdf. but they are not generated in the order they exist. output file is a random file.

Input files:

```
Avinash 123.pdf
Avinash 845.pdf
Avinash 963.pdf
```

output file :

```
Avinash.pdf
```

(in which first Avinash 123.pdf should be there, after this pdf Avinash 845.pdf and so on..)

currently i am using below script

```
@echo off 
pdftk *.pdf cat output Brentwood.pdf
```

is this achievable using pdftk??

Comment: You need to put into the run string the file names explicitly in the order you require. You cannot rely on the order in which `*.pdf` will expand.

Comment: the pdf files gets generated daily with different employee ids on the pdf names

Comment: So what determines the order of their inclusion?

Comment: based on the time they gets generated

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate a file list in the required order, then incorporate it into the `pdftk` run string:-

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set pdfs=
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /od /b *.pdf') do set pdfs=!pdfs! "%%f"
pdftk %pdfs% cat output Brentwood.pdf
```

Note:-

- You need to use delayed expansion in order to use the current value of `pdfs` in each pass of the `for` loop.
- The `dir` parameters list the file names only, in date/time order, and `%%f` is set to each file in turn.
- As the list is built, quotes are needed around `%%f` because of the spaces in the file names.

This slightly round-about solution is because there appear to be no `pdftk` options to work with an external file list.